# flutter web records only mouse movements, and not the screen

Tags: flutter-web, screen-recording

I am trying to record screen sessions in a simple hello world flutter web.

I am allready tries using Hotjar, Inspectlet, Smartlook as third party SW for the screen recording.

I implement the code each of the application in the index.html as instructed by each SW.

I only see mouse movements but the screen is blank (happen in all 3 apps).

When I use the network inspect I see that I get status response 200 when reaching the recording app (and there is a nre recorded session with mouse movements, so I know the code works)

As I understand, the above SW can't fetch the css files from the website the static pages are hosting, after the session ends.

I am building hosting the pages using codeMagic, the website is [here](https://prickly-bear-frontend.codemagic.app/)

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: I also have the same issue. Hotjar records only mouse movements from the Flutter web app. Do you found the solution? Or is the issue with the Flutter framework?

Answer (score 1):

A late response but according to Smartlook's documentation you need to allow it to record canvas which flutter is using.

all you need to do is add to the body tag in the index.html file `data-sl="canvas-mq"`

https://web.developer.smartlook.com/docs/canvas

[image]